# Unable to use the protobuf package

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

It appears that I cannot import this package: `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto`

When I try to `build` or use `go get` I get:

```
cannot load github.com/golang/protobuf/proto: module github.com/golang/protobuf@latest (v1.3.2) found, but does not contain package github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

It is a popular package, I am surprised it does not seem to be working.
https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshal

Has anybody encountered this?

**Update**:

I am simply trying to import this:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)
```

GoLang does not resolve proto in the above path...

I try to install like this:

```
$ go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf/proto latest
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto: module github.com/golang/protobuf@upgrade (v1.3.2) found, but does not contain package github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

**Update2**, not sure how the file helps but here it is:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    "go_poc/plugins/com_styx_proto"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("styxBotDetect plugin is loaded!")
}

func (r registrable) RegisterHandlers(f func(
    name string,
    handler func(
        context.Context,
        map[string]interface{},
        http.Handler) (http.Handler, error),
)) {
    f(pluginName, r.registerHandlers)
}

func (r registrable) registerHandlers(ctx context.Context, extra map[string]interface{}, handler http.Handler) (http.Handler, error) {
// skipping some lines here

styxRqBytes, err := proto.Marshal(styxRq)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusNotAcceptable)
            return
        }

// more code
```

Comment: `go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` works just fine. Please show the code you want to run. Also what version of Go are you using?

Comment: go version go1.13.1 darwin/amd64

Comment: It works for me. It might be a Go module config error for you. Try running `go mod tidy`, then `go build`.

Comment: strange, I get this for tidy:go: failed to lock file at /Users/CoolUser/go/pkg/mod/cache/lock

Comment: I cannot seem to import my local packages as well, maybe the problems are related

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal go file. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200295/discussion-between-failedunittest-and-icza).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there was something wrong with the module cache, that's why the `go` tool was not able to fetch / update dependencies.

In such cases, clearing the module cache (might) help:

```
go clean -modcache
```

Comment: Any idea how the cache got into a bad state? Is there a test to verify the current integrity of the cache without clearing it?

Comment: Not sure, maybe it has something to do with me rearranging the directories of my packages a bit.

Answer (score 1):

On the Terminal window, please run the following commands,

```
go clean -modcache

go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

Then run the following commands to get the packages downloaded and update in the .mod  file

```
go mod init Version1
go mod tidy
```